# Execute MSI command i Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to execute "Install.msi /silent" on a click.

The Code i have

```
 private void Icon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("c:/Data/install /Silent");

    }
```

This will not work, but if remove the "/silent" part i will execute the file. (but not in silent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`Process::Start Method (String^, String^`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx)

The first parameter is the program name, and the second is command line arguments, so you call it like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("c:/Data/install.msi", "/Silent");
```

The function you used [`Process::Start Method (String^)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx) get only executable name, and meant to work without command line arguments. So if you give program with arguments, it is not found.

Comment: I can't find reason why not, but you can try and verify it.